# How to Screenshot Of the Screen on Samsung Galaxy S 2?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, screenshots

Since i have updated my phone by Android version 4.0.3 i am not able to take a screen shot of my phone, before i used to do it by pressing Home and Power button simultaneously.

Now if i am pressing Home and Power button simultaneously it open up Task Manager.

Can someone explain me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Galaxy S3 it is Home and Power but they need to be held in for about 1 second but it may be different on the S2

EDIT: According to [this](http://www.jayceooi.com/2012/03/17/how-to-take-screenshot-on-android-4-0-ics-samsung-galaxy-s2) Samsung have changed the Screen shot buttons to be Volume down + power on some firmware versions and on others it is Power + home heald for about 2 seconds. Hope that helps

Comment: [Samsung Galaxy S2][Android 4.0.3] It's Down + Power for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-i9300) updated OTA to Android 4.3 screenshots are taken by simultaneously holding Power+Home and the screenshot is saved under `/storage/emlated/0/Pictures/Screenshots`.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to take screenshot on Samsung S2 is press & hold the power & home button together. There is more ways to capture screenshot. You can find these ways by [clicking here..](https://technoradars.com/how-to-screenshot-on-samsung/)

Answer (score -1):

i was on the same situation like yours.. my S2 updated about one month ago.. do press your home button together with lock or power button and hold it for about 2 seconds.. press it together not separately and hold.. best of luck.. ;)